# How to call N number of APIs in for loop in swift iOS and upadate array in background. for some loop vales api's not called

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

what I need is:

1. From one api I get total number of pages that I have to retrieve.
2. Then, in a for loop, I retrieve each page by making API calls.
   e.g api/page/0,api/page/2...api/page/n
3. I add the retrieved data to a global array,

But, it is not working as I want

```
func callOne(strCat:String,strCount:String) {
    let strURL = strCat + strCount

    let url = NSURL(string: strURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { data, response, error in
        if data != nil {
            do {

                let arr:NSMutableArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSMutableArray

                if arr.count > 0{
                    let dict = arr[0]
                    self.totalPageCount = Int(dict.objectForKey("total_pages") as! Int)

                   let queue = NSOperationQueue()

                    for (var i = 0 ; i < self.totalPageCount; i++)
                    {
                        let blockOperation = NSBlockOperation{
                            self.callNewsApi(String(self.totalPageCount),strCat: strCat, strCount: String(i), complition: { (finished) -> () in

                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() , { () -> Void in
                                    self.collectionView .reloadData()
                                })
                            })
                        }
                        queue.addOperation(blockOperation)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()
 }

 //MARK: Func second
 func callNewsApi(totalCount:String,strCat:String,strCount:String, complition:(finished:Bool)->())
 {

     // EZLoadingActivity.show("Fetching News...", disableUI: false)
     let fullURL = strCat + strCount
     let url = NSURL(string: fullURL)
     let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
     let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { data, response, error in
         if data != nil {
            EZLoadingActivity.hide()
            do {
                let arr:NSMutableArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSMutableArray

                if arr.count > 0{
                    self.arrNews.addObjectsFromArray(arr as NSMutableArray as [AnyObject])
                        self.saveAllNews(fullURL, dict: self.arrNews)
                        complition(finished: true)
                }

            } catch {


            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider seperating the parts `API call` and `data storing` into different methods.

Comment: //This statement is for for global array used for collectionView self.arrNews.addObjectsFromArray(arr as NSMutableArray as [AnyObject])
//This statement is for saving in coredata self.saveAllNews(fullURL, dict: self.arrNews)complition(finished: true)